# JQuery not being executed

Tags: jquery, image, button, html-table

I am working on a website.  Basically, I have two scripts in my website.  The first script is being executed well.  However, the second script won't work.

Basically, what I want to do is that if the user clicks on a button, certain elements on the page are hidden whilst others are shown.  The elements in question are tables (NOT asp tables).

Here is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Open_Window()
        {
            window.open("DonationConfirmation.aspx")
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#PayPalButton1").click(function () {
                $("#PayPalTableButton").show();
                $("#DonationsTableButton").hide();
            });
            $("#GoogleButton1").click(function () {
                $("#PayPalTableButton").hide();
                $("#DonationsTableButton").show();
            });            
        });
    </script>
```

The first script, that is, function `Open_Window()` is working perfectly.

However, the second script, written in jQuery, won't work.

Here is the code of the buttons (in the form of images) and the tables.

```
<asp:Image ID="PayPalButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="Resources/Icons/PayPal.jpg" onmouseover="this.style.cursor = 'pointer';" Height="65px" Width="130px" />

<asp:Image ID="GoogleButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="Resources/Icons/Google.jpg" onmouseover="this.style.cursor = 'pointer';" Height="65px" Width="130px" />

<table id="PayPalTableButton" runat="server" style="margin:auto; text-align:center; width:100%;">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:center; height:60px;">
                                    //Code
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                        <table id="DonationsTableButton" runat="server" style="margin:auto; text-align:center; width:100%;">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:center; height:60px;">
                                    //Code
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
```

Comment: What do you mean, "doesnt work"? Have you used an error console to see if the code is executing but errors? Have you thrown an "alert" into the jquery wrapper to see if it is executing? Do you have jquery loading? More details - particularly in the javascript area would make this easier to answer.

Comment: Basically, in my master page I have the following line:

<script type="text/javascript" src="Resources/jquery.min.js"></script>

By doesn't work, I am saying that simply nothing happens whenever I click on any of the two buttons (that is, PayPalButton1 and GoogleButton1).  The tables are not hidden/shown.  Everything remains the same as if no click event occurred.

Comment: I'd suggest editing the question to include that.  But, you need to debug your script.  I would suggest running in Firefox, and launching the Tools->Developer Tools->Error Console and seeing what is happening.  We can't tell if your jQuery is loading at all based on this question.  You have to establish that part first, then we can help debug the code that you do have.

Comment: I ran the website with the error console on as suggested.  Nothing comes up in the error console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET transforms the button ID's into something else.

Set the `ClientIDMode` to `Static` on each button.

Comment: Or in the JS use: $("#<%= PayPalButton1.ClientID %>") to merge in what the ClientID wouild be